# Radiobutton styling with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my Radio button with CSS. When the button is unchecked it should have a black border and and when its checked the circle should be completely black. Sadly my Code doesn't work.

**My Code:**

```
<div class="radioss">
      <input type="radio" id="mann" name="selector">
      <label for="mann">Mann</label>
</div>
<div class="radios">
      <input type="radio" id="mann" name="selector">
      <label for="mann">Frau</label>
</div>



.radioss{
    float:left;
}

.radios{
   float:left; 
}

/*Radiobutton*/
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

.mann:not(checked) + label:before{
    content:" ";  
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 13px;
    height:13px;
    border-radius:7px;
}

.mann:checked + label:before{
 background-color:black;
}
```

Does somebody have any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: your radios have an `id`, but your selector tries to find a `class`. Change `id="mann"` to `class="mann"` (as an `id` should only be present once in a document). Also give them a unique id, and the label should correspond to that. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2bns5cua/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/7youc0fz/

Comment: any live example available?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use same or single ID for more than one elements, It won't work.

```css
.radioss input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.radioss input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
   border-radius:7px;
}
.radioss input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
   border-radius:7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioss">
      <input type="radio" id="mann" name="selector">
      <label for="mann">Mann</label>
      <input type="radio" id="mann1" name="selector">
      <label for="mann1">Frau</label>
</div>
```

Source: [Checkbox styling only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234374/checkbox-styling-only-css/40234773#40234773)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link 
its may help you.

```
.checkbox-form .lg-label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #afaeae;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .lg-item-radio .checkbox-form .lg-label:before {
   border-color: rgba(27, 205, 128, 0.6);
}
```

https://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/dZvXjK